# Formatting issue while exporting data to Excel using VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, qlikview

I am using below VBS code to export one chart (from QlikView) to excel.
Reason I am using Number format = ‘@’ and paste special because if I do not use it then values in the chart like ‘22001E-07’ gets converted to 2.20E-03

```
sub GPOTest1
set oXL=CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
oXL.visible=True 
oXL.Workbooks.Add
aSheetObj=Array("CH01")
for i=0 to UBound(aSheetObj)
oXL.Sheets.Add   
Set oSH = oXL.ActiveSheet
oSH.Range("A1").Select   
Set obj = ActiveDocument.GetSheetObject(aSheetObj(i))

obj.CopyTableToClipboard True
oSH.Columns("B").NumberFormat = "@" ‘In “B” column I get values like 22001E-07
oSH.PasteSpecial -4163

sCaption=obj.GetCaption.Name.v
set obj=Nothing     
oSH.Rows("1:1").Select
oXL.Selection.Font.Bold = True       
oSH.Cells.Select
oXL.Selection.Columns.AutoFit 
oSH.Range("A1").Select     
oSH.Name=left(sCaption,30)   
set oSH=Nothing  
next
set oXL=Nothing
end sub
```

After running it for the first time, from 2nd time I get message

> PasteSpecial method of Worksheet class failed

Referred following link, however, issue persists:
[use macro to convert number format to text in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892688/use-macro-to-convert-number-format-to-text-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't systematically create an Excel instance. Your code leaves Excel open. Once Excel is open, the next time around, you can get a reference to it using `GetObject`. See the approach taken in the code below, where I've also simplified a couple things:

```
Sub GPOTest1()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    If oXL Is Nothing Then
        Set oXL = GetObject(Class:="Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    oXL.Visible = True

    Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
    aSheetObj = Array("CH01")

    For i = 0 To UBound(aSheetObj)
        Set oSH = oWB.Sheets.Add

        Set obj = ActiveDocument.GetSheetObject(aSheetObj(i))
        obj.CopyTableToClipboard True

        oSH.Columns("B").NumberFormat = "@" 'In “B” column I get values like 22001E-07
        oSH.PasteSpecial -4163

        oSH.Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True
        oSH.Columns.AutoFit
        oSH.Range("A1").Select
        oSH.Name = Left(obj.GetCaption.Name.v, 30)

        Set oSH = Nothing
        Set obj = Nothing
    Next

    Set oXL = Nothing
End Sub
```